# Angular 9 Mat-select comma separation of values during display

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular9, angular-material-11

I want to present all the values present in the mat-select as comma separated values
and I don't want to have a multiple selection
any suggestions/anybody faced a similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

i got an answer
We can use mat-select-trigger for showing values which are not in the mat-options
got a reference from
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-trigger?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html